# "Method is not supported" error when trying to invoke a delegate

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, silverlight, delegates

I have a function `Run(string, string[])` which I want to run on a separate thread, so I am using a delegate and `BeginInvoke`:

```
private Func<string, string[], Stack<StackItem>> runner;

public MainPage()
{
    runner = Run;
}

private void btnStep_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // snip
    runner.BeginInvoke(tbCode.Text, GetArgs(), null, null); // Exception here
    // snip
}

private Stack<StackItem> Run(string program, string[] args)
{
    return interpreter.InterpretArgs(parser.Parse(lexer.Analyse(program)), args);
}
```

However, I get a `NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code` with a message of `Specified method is not supported` for the `BeginInvoke()` method of the delegate. What's going wrong?

I am using Silverlight 4.0 and VS2010.

Comment: The delegate has three arguments, you are passing only two.  How does this compile?

Comment: @Hans: The delegate has 2 arguments, the `Stack<StackItem>` is the return type (it's a `Func` rather than an `Action`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The asynchronous Delegate.BeginInvoke is not available for delegates in Silverlight.

You should use a [BackgroundWorker instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(VS.95).aspx) to run anything asynchronously.