# Silverlight: Why does BeginInvoke throw a NotSupported exception?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

Why does this code throw a `NotSupported` exception?

```
Action a = () =>
{
    var x = 0;
};

AsyncCallback cb = (IAsyncResult ar) =>
{
    var x = 0;
};


a.BeginInvoke(cb, null);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Method is not supported" error when trying to invoke a delegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516161/method-is-not-supported-error-when-trying-to-invoke-a-delegate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight doesn't support this.

Instead, you can use a BackgroundWorker or the ThreadPool.

Comment: Ok... then why does it compile?

Comment: Because the method exists and its behavior is to throw a NotSupportedException.

Comment: @Josh: But why does it exist?

Comment: Well that's a different question entirely. He asked why it compiled. I'm guessing it was for binary compatibility with WPF but who knows.

Comment: @Josh - Because they didn't want write a special C# compiler just for Silverlight.  The BeginInvoke and Invoke methods are auto-generated for a delegate type, they have arguments that match the delegate declaration.