# Threading in property setter

Tags: c#, multithreading, compact-framework, properties, invoke

I have two properties. The first one is an integer property, this is an ID. The second one is a String, it's corresponding to the ID.
When I set the ID, I will set the correspondent string property in a separate thread.
The code snipet is:

```
public int FirstPlaceId 
{
    set 
    {
        firstPlaceId = value;
        setPlaceNameDelegate d = new setPlaceNameDelegate( setPlaceName );
        IAsyncResult iar = d.BeginInvoke( value, null, null );
        FirstPlace = d.EndInvoke( iar );
    }
    get { return firstPlaceId; } 
}

public string FirstPlace { set; get; }

private string setPlaceName(int id) 
{
    return "alma"; 
}

delegate String setPlaceNameDelegate( int id );

methodus() 
{
   FirstPlaceId = 5; 
}
```

I think it looks like ok. But in runtime when I assign some value (5) to the FirstPlaceId property, the NotSupportedException error occurs.
Why and what is the solution?
Thx

Comment: Just don't use BeginInvoke, there's no point when you call EndInvoke right away.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your issue. Which .NET Framework are you using?

With that said, I don't see the benefit of using `BeginInvoke`/threading in your sample code since it will immediately wait for the delegate call to complete (with `EndInvoke`). That property will just block and is functionally the same this one:

```
public int FirstPlaceId
{
    set 
    {
        firstPlaceId = value;
        FirstPlace = setPlaceName(value);
    }
    get { return firstPlaceId; }
}
```

Just remove `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: The begininvoke is my second trial. First I've tried to start a Thread with same result. I'm using .Net CF 2.0 using windows mobile sdk 6.

Comment: BeginInvoke is not supported in CF or Silverlight. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062930/threadstart-begininvoke-throws-notsupportedexception-on-compact-framework and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516161/method-is-not-supported-error-when-trying-to-invoke-a-delegate.

Comment: I'm using Begininvoke implicitly: there is a web service call in my CF WM6 application and the VS2008 has created the appropriate proxy class to webservice call and it's containing asynchron calls using BeginInvoke. The webservice calling working fine.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert in CF. I retagged your question to add CF. Hopefully, others more knowledgeable in CF will take notice of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SetFirstPlaceId(int value)
{
    firstPlaceId = value;
    Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        FirstPlace = setPlaceName(1);
    });
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
}
```

EDIT: code fixed to actually start the `Thread`.

With this modification it just works fine for me.
(And I'm not a C# expert so I don't know for sure, but I guess that your `delegate` doesn't support `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` for some reason.)